# Autocomplete attribute in html form not working

Tags: php, html

I want to have an update option in my html form in which user enters First_name then all the fields should be autofilled with corresponding values in mysql table.
I tried to use autocomplete attribute in few fields and it is not working.Please check the code and let me know if there is any error.Or any other way to implement the requirement.

```html
 
    <form method="post" action="demo1.php" autocomplete="on">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact_css.css">
    <!--Create a table -->

    <table>
    <tr><td><b>Contact Information</b></td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
    <div class="leftside">
      <td>ContactID</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="ContactID" autocomplete="ContactID"></td>
    </div>
 <div class="rightside">
   <td>ContactOwner</td>
 <!--  <td><input type="text" name="ContactOwner"></td>-->
     <td><select name="ContactOwner">
     <option value="None">None</option>
     <option value="Malik">Malik</option>
     <option value="Manish">Manish</option>
     <option value="Ankit">Ankit</option>
     <option value="Vikrant">Vikrant</option>
     </select></td>
   </div>
    <tr>
 <div class="rightside">
   <td>LeadSource</td>
   <td><select name="LeadSource">
     <option value="None">None</option>
     <option value="Advertisement">Advertisement</option>
     <option value="ColdCall">ColdCall</option>
     <option value="EmployeeReferral">EmployeeReferral</option>
     <option value="ExternalReferral">ExternalReferral</option>
     <option value="OnlineStore">OnlineStore</option>
     <option value="Partner">Partner</option>
     <option value="Web">Web</option>
     <option value="TradeShow">TradeShow</option>
    </select></td>
   <!--<td><input type="text" name="LeadSource"></td>-->
 </div>
      
    <div class="leftside">
   <td><label for="First_name">First_name</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="First_name" name="First_name" autocomplete="First_name"></td>
    </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <div class="rightside">
   <td>Middle_name</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="Middle_name" autocomplete="Middle_name"></td>
     </div>
      <td>Last_name</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="Last_name" autocomplete="Last_name"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>AccountName</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="AccountName"></td>
  
       <td>EmailID</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="EmailID"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Department</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="Department"></td>
      <td>Phone</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="Phone"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
   <td>Mobile</td>
   <td><input type="number" name="Mobile"></td>
   <td>Fax</td>
   <td><input type="number" name="Fax"></td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
   <td>DOB</td>
   <td><input type="date" name="DOB"></td>
   <td>Assistant</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="Assistant"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
   <td>AsstPhone</td>
   <td><input type="number" name="AsstPhone"></td>
   <td>ReportsTo</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="ReportsTo"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>LinkedIn</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="LinkedIn"></td>
   <td>CallStatus</td>
   <td><select name="CallStatus">
     <option value="None">None</option>
     <option value="AnsweringMachine">AnsweringMachine</option>
     <option value="Callback">Callback</option>
     <option value="NotInterested">NotInterested</option>
     <option value="Prospect">Prospect</option>
     <option value="WrongContact">WrongContact</option>
     <option value="PerformedInternally">PerformedInternally</option>
     <option value="LessThan30Employee">LessThan30Employee</option>
     </select></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   
    <!-- Second table-->
    <table>
    <tr><td><b>Address Information</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <div class="leftside">
      <td>Street</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="Street"></td>
     </div>
  <div class="rightside">
   <td>OtherStreet</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="OtherStreet"></td>
  </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <div class="leftside">
   <td>City</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="City"></td>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
   <td>State</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="State"></td>
     </div>
     </tr>
     <tr>
   <td>Zip</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="Zip"></td>
   <td>Country</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="Country"></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
    <!--Third table-->
  <table>
    <tr><td><b>Description Information</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Description</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="Description" class="Description"></td>
    
  </table>
  <button type="button">Cancel</button>
 <!-- <button type="submit">Save and New</button>-->
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
  
   </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: input autocomplete attribute has value `on|off`

Comment: The HTML autocomplete is for internet browsers as far as I know (so it'll autocomplete the values it knows, e.g. the username and the password which is saved for a site). Use the PHP code to "force" values into it. e.g. you got mobile number, lets say you want ot autocomplete it, so just write $<input type="number" value=<?php echo $mynumbervalue; ?>>$

Comment: Read the autocomplete section here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input  . it says "The browser is allowed to automatically complete the value based on values that the user has entered during previous uses". That means the browser's own cache of what that user on that machine has typed before, and not always into your site either. I don't know where you got the idea that this would have anything to do with fetching data from databases? For that you need a server-side database and a PHP script to query the database and return the data to the web page.

Comment: Also, if you think about it, where in your code is it mentioning that it's _your_ database to pull the values from? There's no place to add that info. I can't understand why you thought this would work, or where you read that it would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not how `autocomplete` attribute is working.

> **Definition and Usage**
>
> The autocomplete attribute specifies whether or not an input field
>   should have autocomplete enabled.
>
> Autocomplete allows the browser to predict the value. When a user
>   starts to type in a field, the browser should display options to fill
>   in the field, **based on earlier typed values**.
>
> *Note: The autocomplete attribute works with the following 
>   types: text, search, url, tel, email, password, datepickers, range,
>   and color.*

**SYNTAX**

`<input autocomplete="on|off">`

This attribute can have only value **on** or **off**

Refer to [**w3schools**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp) docs for more details

If you want to have a default value in those fields you can set it inside [**value**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp) attribute or design your database with `DEFAULT` values.

So you can change `<input type="text" name="ContactID" autocomplete="ContactID">` to `<input type="text" name="ContactID" value="ContactID">`